# Adding Next and Prev Button for Thumbnails Gallery and Larger Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the next and prev button for both thumbnail and larger image gallery. And that next and prev button should support the keyboard event listeners too.

This is the link which I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/36/

I need some help.

Comment: Hello, It's me again. What are those ugly attributes? http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/2/ was cleaner...

Comment: @Oriol: Hi actuaaly I want to set that to my code. There was some changes in my code. Previously I was using XML. But now I am not. Can you edit that to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/37/

The problem is

```
$(['next','prev']).each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $('#'+that).click(function(){
        $('#thumbs img.clicked')[that]().click();
    });
});
```

because now you have

```
<a href="#" id="tnext">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="tprev">Prev</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" id="lnext">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="lprev">Prev</a>
```

So the solution is;

```
$(['next','prev']).each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $('.'+that).click(function(){
        $('#thumbs .clicked')[that]().click();
    });
});
```

and

```
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
```

Comment: But the functionality for next and prev for both thumbnails and larger images should be different.

Comment: because thumbnails should show its images and larger images should show its, But onclick of each thumbnail the particluar larger image will be shown

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete solution for above issue for adding next and previous buttons.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7y

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div class="controls">
    <img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1698581142461241089.png" class="prev" />
    <span>
      Thumbnail Navigation 
    </span>
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0760/resultset_next.png" class="next" />
  </div>


  <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="thumb active">
      <img src="http://images.replacements.com/images/images5/china/C/lenox_china_garden_birds_no_box_P0000014675S0122T2.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://coolfunnyanimals.com/thumb/funny-animal-bird-47.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://learnordie.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thrasher.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_N_mOB63qPaE/TSC17ceXRII/AAAAAAAARaQ/TeDi9FYIBPw/s1600/Flying-Bird-Picture-2.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://www.kevinhearne.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/pic6.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="controls" align="center" width="400px">
    <img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1698581142461241089.png" class="prev" />
    <span>
      Large Image Navigation 
    </span>
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0760/resultset_next.png" class="next" />
  </div>


  <div id="large">
    <div class="bigthumb active">
      <img src="http://images.replacements.com/images/images5/china/C/lenox_china_garden_birds_no_box_P0000014675S0122T2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://coolfunnyanimals.com/thumb/funny-animal-bird-47.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://learnordie.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thrasher.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_N_mOB63qPaE/TSC17ceXRII/AAAAAAAARaQ/TeDi9FYIBPw/s1600/Flying-Bird-Picture-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://www.kevinhearne.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/pic6.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#thumbs{
  text-align:center;
  background:#77a5c6;
  padding:5px;
}
.thumb{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#thumbs .active{
  border:3px solid #333;
}
.controls{
  margin-left:10px;
}
.controls img{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0px;
}
.controls span{
  font-size:13px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-top:5px;
}
#large{
  text-align:center;
}
#large .bigthumb{
  display:none;
}
#large .active{
  display:block;
}
#large .active img{
  border:2px solid #333;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:first").addClass("active");
    $("#large").find(".bigthumb:first").addClass("active");

    var getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();

    $(".controls").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".next").click(function() {
            getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();
            getIndex += 1;
            if (getIndex > ($("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1)) {
                getIndex = 0;
            }
            setActiveImage(getIndex);
        });
        $(this).find(".prev").click(function() {
            getIndex -= 1;
            if (getIndex < 0) {
                getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1;
            }
            setActiveImage(getIndex); //Set/Show Active Image
        });
    });

});

function setActiveImage(index) {
    if (typeof(index) == "undefined" || index == "" || index == null) index = 0;

    $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").removeClass("active");
    $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
    $("#large").find(".bigthumb").removeClass("active");
    $("#large").find(".bigthumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7y

Comment: I completed this task I have an issue I posted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158433/facing-issue-in-thumbnail-gallery-next-and-prev-buttons