# Issue in Image Thumbnail Gallery next and prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actual need for me is Initially I need to show 3thumbnail images. As I clicked on next the next three new thumbnail images should be displayed. If you refer this link 
http://www.frontendwebhelp.com/javascript/jquery-photo-gallery.php

this is what exactly I needed. Here the next and prev buttons functionality is different for thumbnail images and larger image.

I should not use any kind of carousel plugin to get this effect.

Here it is what I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/37/

I need some help.

Comment: On your example, they both behave the same way because they both have the same class. If you want different behaviours you'll need different classes and functions accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/60/

```
function thumbs(i,incr){
    var num_thumbs=2;
    if(i===null){
        i=$("#thumbs").prop('data-index'),
        i+=num_thumbs*incr;
    }
    i=Math.max(1,Math.min(i,$('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow').length-num_thumbs+1));
    $("#thumbs").prop('data-index',i);
    $('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow').hide();
    $('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow:nth-child(n+'+i+'):nth-child(-n+'+Number(i+num_thumbs-1)+')').show();
}
$("#panel .UiUx3DSSVFlow").not(':first').hide();
$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow").click(function(){
    getIndex = $(this).index();
    $("#thumbs .clicked").removeClass('clicked');
    $("#panel .UiUx3DSSVFlow").hide().eq(getIndex).show();  
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    thumbs(getIndex+1);        
});
$("#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow:first").click();
$("#thumbs").prop('data-index',1);
$([['next',1],['prev',-1]]).each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $('#t'+that[0]).click(function(){
        thumbs(null,that[1]);
    });
    $('#l'+that[0]).click(function(){
        $('#thumbs .clicked')[that[0]]().click();
    });
});
$('#tprev').click();
```

Comment: Hi again I am  some issues in your answered code. i am trying to keep the images and videos in my gallery. Here it is what I am trying as you tried: http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/5/. I need a help brother. Please help me out. Functionality and Requirement is same as it was previous. But extra I added videos too which are necessary now in gallery

Comment: @uii See http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/7/. Your jsfiddle uses Mootols instead of jQuery, and it's `$("#larger .UiUx3DSSVFlow")` instead of `$("#larger.UiUx3DSSVFlow")`. Moreover, I don't understand why do you want a thumbs gallery which shows only one element at once...

Comment: Is there any other method to achieve this gallery concept without using any plugins of jquery

Comment: I added a new div for video part but it showing some issue. Its not coming like before, as the updated one which u sent me. http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/8/. Please help me out with this last issue

Comment: @See http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/9/. All `.UiUx3DSSVFlow` should be siblings: use `<div id="Video" class="UiUx3DSSVFlow"><div class="video_gallery"><div>` instead of `<div id="Video"><div class="video_gallery"><div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow">`

Comment: As the gallery ends, as I click on next then it should comes to first image again. like this if i click on prev on 1st image then it should goes to last one. But as I am clicking on Video why its not opening in larger gallery.

Comment: @uii Thumbnails should be images, it doesn't work with videos. So you should take an screenshot of the video and use it instead of the video itself.

Comment: As I am clicking on thumbnail gallery images the selected thumbnail large image should come but its not coming and also the next and prev buttons for larger image is not working. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/10/.

Comment: Please help me out brother. The larger image on click of thumbnails are not coming. And also the next and prev button are not working for larger image

Comment: Hi brother please help me for solving the above issue that is with larger images

Comment: @uii Use `$("#larger .UiUx3DSSVFlow")` instead of `$("#larger.UiUx3DSSVFlow")`